# High kernel_task CPU usage problem

Tags: mac, performance, cpu, temperature

I have an old MacBook Air 13" from 2013. It has been working flawlessly up to maybe 6 months ago, where it started being insanely slow. I have identified the cause to be the dreaded kernel_task, that uses all my CPU.

The problem starts right after booting (maybe even during booting, it is very slow as well). The system CPU usage is constantly at 65-85%, where the free CPU can be 0.2-25%. The kernel_task is a 200-1000%. As it starts during booting, I don't believe it is actually high temperatures. Also the fan is very silent and the computer does not appear hot. There is no difference if I am on battery or power source. Ambient temperature is probably 21oC. When starting the Mac, I have to hold the start button until the apple logo appears, as it otherwise won't start.

Here is a view of the activity monitor:
[image]

What I have tried so far:

- Reset SMC
- Reset PRAM
- De-dust the macbook
- Update to the latest IOS
- Reset to factory settings and remove everything
- Deactivate turbo boost

What I have tried for screening the problem

- Run "sudo powermetrics --samplers smc" in terminal. CPU thermal level: 150. CPU die temperature: 50oC. Fan: 1200 RPM
- Run intel power gadget

[image]

- Install Macs fan control and set to a high speed for a period, to cool the computer. Did not stop the kernel_task.
- Boot in safe mode (still occurred).
- Apple diagnostics only gave PPT002 "Battery functions normally, but the voltage is lower than when it was new"

What can I do to make my computer usable again? Resetting it did improve, as I before generally had <1% CPU available, but it is still not doing great.

Comment: Does this still occur in Safe Mode (boot with Shift key held down)?

Comment: It still occurs in safe mode, no difference there.

Comment: Not sure if related, but I can add that I have to hold down the start button when booting the computer until the start-up sound is more or less done and the apple logo appears. It also makes a loud sound, like winding or something, which I do not believe is from the speakers

Comment: @BastianBorumAndersen Can you elaborate on what you mean by `have to hold down the start button`? Do you mean that the computer won't boot unless you press AND hold the button? Does it suddenly turn off if you release the button prematurely?

Comment: Exactly Pion. I have to press and hold down for maybe 5-10s? Otherwise it immediately goes to black. Not sure if it is related though

Comment: Can you provide the output of: `kextstat | grep X86Platform`

Comment: Also what is your battery cycle count? (Apple Menu > About This Mac > System Report > Power > Cycle Count)

Comment: Which macOS?...

Comment: Did you solve this sir ?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no clear hint as to what's causing `kernel_task` to use >200% CPU at boot, we need to start at first principles and examine what the kernel is doing. The way to do this is by collecting and analyzing a **spindump**. To do this:

1. Run the following *Terminal* command to enable kernel symbolication:

   ```
    sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"
   ```

   Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a general error, you will first need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection). You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. **Reboot your machine** and don’t open any apps except for *Terminal*.
3. In *Terminal*, enter the following command, press <kbd>Return</kbd>, type in your password, but **do not press <kbd>Return</kbd> again yet**:

   ```
    sudo spindump -reveal -noProcessingWhileSampling
   ```
4. Perform the minimum actions that are necessary in order to put the system into its high-CPU usage state. In your case maybe this just means waiting a few moments.
5. As soon as you begin to feel the slowness, go to the *Terminal* window where you entered your password and press <kbd>Return</kbd> so that the command begins to execute. Do not do anything else on the computer while it's running, otherwise you will distort the data collection.
6. After waiting for >10 seconds to collect a sample and another minute or two to symbolicate and format, you’ll get a file in `/tmp/spindump.txt` that contains a stackshot of every process.
7. Upload the file to [PasteBin](https://www.pastebin.com) or some equivalent place and add the link to it to your original question. We can take a look at it and come up with next steps for the investigation.